# Order one table based on column of another using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to implement a join so then I can order results of one table based on the column of another table. My SQL works perfectly when the records exists in both tables. The SQL also works when there are more records in table1 than there are in table2, providing I do not use the `ORDER BY` clause.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
 JOIN table2 b ON table1.col1 = b.col1 
 WHERE col3 != 0 ORDER BY b.col2 ASC;
```

Table 1

```
col1 | col2 | col3
__________________
1      foo    1
2      foo    1
5      foo    1
9      foo    0
10     foo    1
17     foo    0
14     foo    1
12     foo    1
```

Table 2

```
col1 | col2
___________
1       a
2       b
17      e
14      g
12      l
```

The part of the query `ORDER BY b.col2 ASC` is causing it to fail when the records between the two tables are not matching.

I cannot guarantee that a record will be present in both. Is there a way of still implementing this?

I am currently using `mysqli` but can use `pdo` if needed.

Comment: Try a LEFT JOIN maybe ?

Comment: Where in the order should it go if there's no matching record?

Comment: (Aside: the community has several times discussed whether to permit home-made tags in question titles, and it's been decided [that we should not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256806/472495). Thought you'd want to know).

Comment: @Maximus2012 i have just tried this and the outcome was the same unfortunately.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning in that case you might need to add additional condition checking in your query (CASE WHEN <...>). Understand that you can't order by a column if there are no values for that column. If you could update your question with the exact table structure you have, some sample data along with the desired output then that would be helpful.

Comment: Also, it does not matter if you use mysqli or pdo. You need to get the basic MySQL query right first.

Comment: You might also want to update your question with that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Maximus2012 the above table structure is an exact match of what I am dealing with.

Comment: What should the desired output look like ?

Comment: At this point it would be nice just to get the query to work without an error. But ultimately I would like all the records in `table1` order by `col2` within `table2`. Which currently works perfect if the records match. I would like it so that if the records do not match then that record is at the bottom of the results.

Comment: Please see the answer that I added and see if it works. If it does not work then it would be helpful if you could create an SQL Fiddle with your tables and sample data and update your question to add a link to it: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Like @Maximus2012 mentioned, try a `LEFT JOIN`.  This will give you all of the records from table1 and any records from table2 which match col1 from table1.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON table1.col1 = b.col1 
WHERE col3 != 0 ORDER BY b.col2 ASC
```

If you are looking for all records from table2 and any which match from table 1, use a `RIGHT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 b ON table1.col1 = b.col1 
WHERE col3 != 0 ORDER BY b.col2 ASC
```

Comment: If you copy an answer like this then please make sure it's an extended version of a comment. Why are you suggesting a Left Join etc.?

Comment: i have just tried this and the outcome was the same unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks but `right join` is also returning the same problem. I am looking for all records in table1 and `order` them by `table2` `col2`. If there is no record in `tables2` then it will be last in the results.

Comment: If there is no value from table 2, where should it be in the results?  `OUTER JOIN`s like `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` use `NULL` for column values when the outer joined table is not matched.  Do you want those records from table 1 to show first instead of last?

Answer (score 0):

Making use of a LEFT JOIN to get this query:

```
SELECT table1.*, 
table2.col2,
CASE WHEN table2.col2 IS NOT NULL THEN '0' 
ELSE '1' END AS derived_column FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 
WHERE table1.col3 <> 0 
ORDER BY derived_column, table2.col2
```

See if the above query works for your case. It is a bit complicated since the ORDER BY clause in the original query will put the non-matching columns before the matching ones in the result. To bypass this, I have conditionally created a derived column to return a value of 0 (for matching) and 1 (for non-matching). Then you order by this derived column first (rows with value 0 will come before those with value 1) and then order by table2.col2.